# Exact scaling with TiKZ-scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale

I am using `tikzscale` to scale all my figures to the same size. This works quite nicely, but sometimes there is a difference in the scaled width. I can manually tweak the scale parameter (using `pdfcrop` and looking at the resulting page width), but it would be easier if the size would be exact right out of `tikzscale`.

In this example the width of the first plot seems a bit too narrow in comparison with the box while the second plot seems too be the widest figure.

> [image]

### **MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{fig.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fig2.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fig3.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[yticklabel style={overlay}]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, axisratio=4]{fig.tikz} 

\vspace{0.1cm}

\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{fig2.tikz} 

\vspace{0.1cm}

\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, axisratio=4]{fig3.tikz} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: This happens because the x tick labels protrude past the axis area. Which part of the axis do you want to be aligned with the middle rectangle? The axis box?

Comment: @Jake, I would like the whole diagramm to have exactly the same size as the box. The whole figure should be aligned not only the axis. I used the example with `yticklabel style={overlay}` since I had a figure where I had several plots below each other and wanted them to align.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tikzscale` correctly scales both axes to the entire text width. However, the  tick labels have white space around them, which is taken into account for the scaling.

You can remove the white space around the tick labels by setting

```
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=0pt
    },
    yticklabel style={
        inner xsep=0pt,
        xshift=-0.333em
    }
}
```

(note the `xshift` for the y tick labels, because they used the `inner xsep` for their positioning)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=0pt
    },
    yticklabel style={
        inner xsep=0pt,
        xshift=-0.333em
    }
}

\begin{filecontents}{fig.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fig2.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) rectangle (1,0.2) coordinate (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fig3.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[yticklabel style={overlay}]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, axisratio=4]{fig.tikz} 

\vspace{0.1cm}

\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{fig2.tikz} 

\vspace{0.1cm}

\includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth, axisratio=4]{fig3.tikz} 

\tikz[remember picture, overlay, red] \draw (A) -- +(0,6cm) -- +(0,-4cm)
(B) -- +(0,4cm) -- +(0,-6cm);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, from your graphic it seems as that my problem would be solved, if the white space around the boxes would be removed or not regarded when scaling. Is that feasible?

Comment: @maetra: I've edited my answer