# TikZ & External: figure re-created for no apparent reason

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external, tikzscale

I'm having an issue where only one out of multiple figures is recreated despite the use of the `tikz/external` library. I've created a MWE which shows the same effect with only two figures.

Below is my main file which is compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape file`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/}{./figures-tikz/} }

\newcommand{\figFilename}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t!]
    \renewcommand{\figFilename}{scalability-plot-all-sbb-2-optima}
    \centering
    \tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,axisratio=1]{\figFilename.tikz}
    \caption{Scalability plot for dDE, MPC, dDE$^-$ and a hill climber on the Scalable-Building-Block problem.}
    \label{fig:\figFilename}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[t!]
    \renewcommand{\figFilename}{scalability-plot-all-sbb-2-optima-log-y}
    \centering
    \tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,axisratio=1]{\figFilename.tikz}
    \caption{Same as in Figure~\ref{fig:scalability-plot-all-sbb-2-optima}, but y axis is in logscale.}
    \label{fig:\figFilename}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The first figure is re-created every time I run `pdflatex`. I tried changing the ordering of the two, but it does not make a difference --- the figure with the filename `scalability-plot-all-sbb-2-optima` is the one that's always re-created even though the other figure is identical but with a `semilogyaxis` instead. The `TikZ` files for both are merely five `addplot` commands which load data from five different .dat files. Showing everything here would take up a lot of space, so here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hh3m7wvubfzshc0/recreation-issue.zip) to the whole directory structure, including the `.tex`, `.tikz` and `.dat` files.

I've found that if I keep only one addplot, the figure is not re-created. I was wondering whether this is a bug, whether `LaTeX` is confused by my directory structure, or whether it's simply a mistake on my part.

Comment: Is this really a MWE, do you need all those packages to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I left it this way in case there was a package incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my very limited LaTeX knowledge, I decided to inspect the log file (`file.log`) to try to identify what went wrong. I noticed that right after the convert command that causes the picture to be re-generated, there was an error of this sort:

```
Overfull \hbox (17.03157pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--76
 [][] 
 []
```

This led me to believe that `tikzscale` was not capable of scaling the picture to the exact size I requested, and this caused a mismatch between what `tikzscale` thought the size of the picture was and what it *actually* was. So what I did was follow the instructions listed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119983/32206) answer to remove the whitespace from around the x and y labels (basically try to help `tikzscale`).

The problem is now fixed. The `Overfull \hbox` warning no longer appears and the picture is not re-generated every time. I do not know whether this is the expected behaviour or whether this is a bug though.